# The windows command line correct path issue in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, path

```
PS D:\>
```

When I am trying to do this →

```
PS D:\> cd Academy/Lynda LinkedIn/PHP/0-Learning Composer The Php Dependency Manager/Exercise Files/02_01
```

It generates this error →

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dN1F.png

Comment: Just  CD  d:\Academy .....

Comment: your target path has _SPACES_ in it ... so you need to enclose it in quotes. [*grin*]

Comment: try `cd acad<tab>` e.t.c. let autocomplete help you.

Comment: Thanks, can someone tell me what is the final to be copy posted.

Comment: `cd 'Academy\Lynda LinkedIn\PHP\0-Learning Composer The Php Dependency Manager\Exercise Files\02_01'`

Comment: Stuff with spaces, special characters, etc., must be properly quoted. See the PowerShell help file on Quoting. [about_Quoting_Rules - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules), and [this article](https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/20/powershell-quoting)

Comment: Thanks → Lieven Keersmaekers and postanote

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the path in quotes because it contains spaces.

```
cd "Academy/Lynda LinkedIn/PHP/0-Learning Composer The Php Dependency Manager/Exercise Files/02_01"
```